# jQuery stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when I click add 'hello' is added to the textarea. But when I manually change the text in textarea the script stop working.
Can you explain why?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").click(function() {
    $('[name="text"]').append('hello');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea name="text" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
<p>add</p>
```

Comment: `$('[name="text"]').val('hello');`

Comment: this change the value to 'hello'. I want to append 'hello'

Comment: do want when manually changed in textarea after that 'add' clicked then all text removed and only hello will replace there?

Comment: you want to apend hello with a hello?

Comment: @seeberg — `$('[name="text"]').val(function(){
return this.value + 'hello';
});`

Comment: It is working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use following **jQuery**::

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").click(function() {
    $('[name="text"]').val(function(){ return this.value.search(/\S/)!=-1 ? this.value + ' hello' : 'hello'; });
  });
});
```

It will append a space with 'hello' if already something is writen in textarea or if blank then will only append 'hello'.

Working link: https://jsfiddle.net/s5zwthe8/

Answer (score -2):

Please push your text using text area id. Like

```
<textarea name="text" rows="10" cols="30" id="appendtext"></textarea>
```

in Jquery Put code :

```
$('#appendtext').text("text");
```

Comment: Yes i have woks like same but you get already solution @rana ghosh so you can use same but if you find simple solution then you can use my trick. Rana's solution is based on Rejex based.